# Android: Get EditText View to take up rest of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Gross Pay"
        />
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Gross Pay"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Continue"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I have tried everything I can think of to make the EditText take up the rest of the screen, however, I am still not doing something right. It looks fine in Eclipse but when I run in an emulator the EditText does not expand as I would expect.

Anyone able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dope! found it this was a fragment and I had to change...

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.manageyobudget.fragment.GeneralTaxInformationFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

To

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.manageyobudget.fragment.GeneralTaxInformationFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..   if you give weight 1 means you need to give 0dp for which you want to match the parent..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Gross Pay"
        />
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Gross Pay"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```